# Scheme letrec infinite environment

Tags: scheme, sicp, letrec

I'm currently writing metacircular evaluator in Scheme, following the SICP book's steps.

In the exercise I am asked to implement `letrec`, which I do in the following way:

```
(define (letrec->let exp)
  (define (make-unassigned var)
    (list var '*unassigned*))
  (define (make-assign binding)
    (list 'set! (letrec-binding-var binding)
          (letrec-binding-val binding)))
  (let ((orig-bindings (letrec-bindings exp)))
    (make-let
     (map make-unassigned
          (map letrec-binding-var orig-bindings))
     (sequence->exp
      (append
       (map make-assign orig-bindings)
       (letrec-body exp))))))
```

However, when I evaluate the expression as follows, it goes into infinite loop:

```
(letrec
  ((a (lambda () 1)))
  (+ 1 (a)))
```

Do I miss anything?

*([Full Source Code at GitHub](http://goo.gl/oW5j0z)).*

Comment: did your code ever worked for the simplest cases like `(let ((x 1)) x)`?

Comment: this question is misleading. the problem in that code is at much deeper (earlier) level and has nothing to do specifically with letrec.

Answer (score 1):

I checked result transformation result of `(let ((x 1)) x)` and got:

`((lambda (x) (x)) 1)`

instead of:

`((lambda (x) x) 1)`

obviously problem is in `let` body processing. If I were you, I would use utility function:

```
(define (implicit-begin exps)
  (if (= 1 (length x))
      (car x)
      (cons 'begin x)))
```

**By the way:** I would say, that your `letrec` implementation is not very correct. Your transformation returns:

```
(let ((x1 *unassigned*>) ... (xn *unassigned*))
  (set! x1 ...)
  ...
  (set! xn ...)
  body)
```

It much more resembles `letrec*` which evaluates expressions for variable bindings in left-ro-right order (Scheme itself doesn't specify arguments evaluation order):

> syntax: letrec* bindings body
>
> ```
>  Similar to ‘letrec’, except the INIT expressions are bound to their
>  variables in order.
>
>  ‘letrec*’ thus relaxes the letrec restriction, in that later INIT
>  expressions may refer to the values of previously bound variables.
> ```

The more correct code would be:

```
(let ((x1 *unassigned*) ... (xn *unassigned*))
  (let ((t1 ...) ... (tn ...))
    (set! x1 t1)
    ...
    (set! xn tn))
  body)
```

Comment: Do you mean to put the implicit-begin in my expand-let function so that it can has (car exps) in lambda body directly?

Comment: the problem is that `make-lambda` assumes something, but `let-body` violates that assumption, in certain situations.